# Excepción no controlada

Tags: c#

cuando compilo me muestra el siguiente texto

> El índice (basado en cero) debe ser mayor o igual a cero y menor que el tamaño de la lista de argumentos.

Mi código

```
  txtTicket.Text += String.Format("|{0,48}|{1,15}|", producto, String.Format("{0:C}"),
        Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecio.Text)) + "\r\n";
```

Comment: ... Y tu pregunta es?

Comment: como quitar lo que me aparece al compilar